# Has anyone any experience of the Flipbac Camera Grips?

Tags: accessories, reviews, canon-s90, battery-grip

I was looking at [Flipbac Grips](http://flipbac.com/where-to-buy-Flipbac.htm) for my Canon S90. Was wondering if anyone had any comments to share about them. Yes I'd prefer Richard Franeic's custom-machined aluminium version but I'm too miserly. Will the G1 or G2 do the job at least competently?

Thanks.

Comment: As seen here: http://cnet.co/q1UKs3

Comment: Thanks to @s95 shooter - I bought all three and have settled on the G1 - it really is a very good solution and I recommend it without reservation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have used both the Flipbac Grip 2 and the RF grip (on my previous S90). The RF grip is nice but the Flipbac Grip is no compromise. I feel it is much better value for money. It fit my S95 perfectly. On a recent weekend trip with my wife it was invaluable. Easy one hand holding. It feels good and looks good.  I don't own my camera long enough to justify the $45 on the RF grip.No regrets.

s95 shooter
Western Australia